# Checkboxlist check uncheck not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to `show/Hide` the div on the basis of selection of `checkbox` values from the list.

Here is what I tried:-

```
function valueChanged() {
    if ($('#ddlStatus_1').is(":checked"))
        $("#divExpense").hide();
    else
        $("#divExpense").show();
}
```

and the html is

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 320px; height: 100px;">
    <table id="Table1" name="Status" onchange="valueChanged()">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ddlStatus_0" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$0" value="20" /><label for="ddlStatus_0">Agreement</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ddlStatus_1" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$1" value="30" /><label for="ddlStatus_1">Registration
                    / Conveyance Deed</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ddlStatus_2" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$2" value="40" /><label for="ddlStatus_2">7/12
                    Transfer on Name</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ddlStatus_3" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$3" value="50" /><label for="ddlStatus_3">Sold</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ddlStatus_4" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$4" value="60" /><label for="ddlStatus_4">Cancelled</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="div1">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="otab">
                This is test Expense Information :
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="divPayment">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="otab">
                This is test Payment Information :
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But it is not working for me.

Comment: You're hiding in both cases of your JS - is this a typo?

Comment: @GeoffJames: in both the cases it is not getting hided but..

Comment: Do you have any errors showing in the console of your developer tools?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Nope there are no errors.

Comment: Seems to me that you've put the handler on the `<table>` - any reason why? This will only detect changes to the table itself, right? Won't you need to put it on the checkbox, instead?

Comment: Do you have an element with id divExpense?

Comment: Ditto to @melli-182 - we cannot see the HTML for `divExpense` - do you definitely have one?

Comment: @mplungjan: it is not working in IE

Comment: You likely want `$(function() { $('#ddlStatus_1').on("click",function() { $("#divExpense").toggle(!this.checked); }); });`

Comment: @mplungjan: not working, and on page load I get error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: You have likely not loaded jQuery? Please see my answer and test it in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a running version of the code in my comment. You do not want to add the change to the table tag. If you need all checkboxes in the form to toggle something, then add a class to them and use data-attributes to see what to toggle

Note I changed div1 to divExpense

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ddlStatus_1').on("click", function() {
     $("#divExpense").toggle(!this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 320px; height: 100px;">
  <table id="Table1" name="Status">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ddlStatus_0" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$0" value="20" />
        <label for="ddlStatus_0">Agreement</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ddlStatus_1" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$1" value="30" />
        <label for="ddlStatus_1">Registration / Conveyance Deed</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ddlStatus_2" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$2" value="40" />
        <label for="ddlStatus_2">7/12 Transfer on Name</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ddlStatus_3" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$3" value="50" />
        <label for="ddlStatus_3">Sold</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ddlStatus_4" type="checkbox" name="ddlStatus$4" value="60" />
        <label for="ddlStatus_4">Cancelled</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="divExpense">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="otab">
        This is test Expense Information :
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="divPayment">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="otab">
        This is test Payment Information :
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: my two jquery plugins are getting conflicted that is why it is not working.

Comment: can you help me with the plugins. here are the two which I am already using. SO how to adjust all the three https://jsfiddle.net/btb6szng/ these plugins are getting conflicted

Comment: superb, now all three are working. thanks a lot Mplungjan.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `change` event to `#ddlStatus_1` instead of `table` like following.

```
$('#ddlStatus_1').change(function() {
    $("#divExpense").toggle(!this.checked);
})
```

Comment: Is there any advantage? @mplungjan

Comment: change for checkbox and radio button click for buttons